# Want to check measure theory proof

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

I need to show that sigma-finiteness implies semifinite. Does the following proof work?

Let $(X,m,\mu)$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure. Let, $E\in m$, and
$\mu(E)=\infty$. By $\sigma-$finiteness, $\exists E_{i},\ i\in\mathbb{N},\ \mu(E_{i})\ \text{finite},\ni X=\cup_{i}E_{i}.$
Now, $\infty=\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap(\cup_{i}E_{i}))=\mu(\cup_{i}(E\cap E_{i}))\leq\sum_{i}\mu(E\cap E_{i})$.
Now, $\exists i\ \ni\mu(E\cap E_{i})\ne0,$and $\mu(E\cap E_{i})<\mu(E)<\infty$. Take $F=E\cap E_{i*}\subset E $ to complete proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we do not know the meaning of $\bigcup_i\mu(E\cap E_i)$. Writing this using limit is probably what was meant in the opening post.

We can write it in the following way: we know that defining $F_n:=E\cap \bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j$, we have $\mu(F_n)\lt\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(F_n)=\mu(E)=+\infty$. Therefore, there is some $n_0$ such that $\mu(F_{n_0})\gt 1$ and we have $F_{n_0}\subset E$, and $\mu(F_{n_0})\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, I was guessing something along these lines, but, could you kindly explain why $\bigcup_i\mu(E\cap E_i)$ cannot be written as I had wrote?

Comment: What is a union of real numbers?

Comment: Ooops, typo, I intended to put a sum. What I meant was, is there a reason one has to use a limiting argument?

Comment: In this case you proof is fine. The set $F$ used in the definition of semifinite comes from an approximation by sets of finite measure.